# Dealing with multiple error checks in NodeJS controller

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise

I need to validate multiple checks in my controller and throw possible errors to my route. Something like this:

Router:

- send post var to controller

Controller:

- throw error if post.categoria is blank
- check in mysql if already exists
- throw error if already exists

Router code:

```
// POST new
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    // get post var
    var post   = {categoria: req.body.categoria};

    // validate
    controller.newCategoria(post).then(
        result => { 
            // return valid result, I'll implement it later
            res.json(result);
        },
        error => {
            // return error to frontend
            res.json(error);
        }
    );

});
```

Controller code:

```
module.exports.newCategoria = async (post) => {
    // throw error if blank
    if (post.categoria.length == 0)
        throw "categoria is empty"; // portuguese

    db.query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM categoria WHERE ?', post, function(err, result) { 
        if (err)
            throw err;
        if (JSON.stringify(result[0].count) >= 1)
            throw new Error("already exists");
    });

    return "ok";
};
```

If I send and existing categoria I get: Rethrow non-MySQL errors

I tried to use a promise:

```
module.exports.newCategoria = async (post) => {
    // check if blank
    if (post.categoria.length == 0)
        throw "blank categoria";

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM categoria WHERE ?', post, function(err, result) { 
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            if (JSON.stringify(result[0].count) >= 1)
                return reject(new Error("already exists"));
            return resolve(result);
        });
    }).then(
        resolve => {
            // ok.. deal with it
            console.log('ok');
            console.log(resolve);
        },
        error => {
            throw error;
        }
    ).catch((error) => {
        throw error;
    });

    return "ok";
};
```

I don't know how to throw it back to rote, I'm getting this error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: already exists

I'm new to NodeJS, I need a good practice for it. Thanks.

Comment: You need to `return` the promise that you're creating, not the strig `"ok"`.

Comment: you are getting already exists error because you are throwing it. I don't see how that code would ever not throw, I would use `Number` instead of `JSON.stringify` for checking if you should throw that error.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm returning the promise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a **Promise** like so

```js
module.exports.newCategoria = async (post) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // throw error if blank
        if (post.categoria.length == 0)
            reject(new Error("categoria is empty")); // make sure you are throwing Errors or else node will chastise you

        db.query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM categoria WHERE ?', post, function(err, result) { 
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else if (Number(result[0].count) >= 1) // compare ints to ints, not string to int
                reject(new Error("already exists"));
            else
                resolve(result)
        });
    })
};
```

If you want to do more async stuff, here is one way you could refactor

```js
const alreadyExists = x => x && x[0] && x[0].length > 1

const getCategoria = post => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(
      'SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM categoria WHERE ?',
      post,
      (err, result) => {
        if (err)
          reject(err)
        else if (alreadyExists(result))
          reject(new Error('already exists'))
        else
          resolve(result)
      },
    )
  })
}

module.exports.newCategoria = async post => {
  const categoria = await getCategoria(post)
  // insert here
}
```

Comment: You are very welcome. I've just made some edits to my post showing you how you could refactor if you wanted to do more async stuff after the insert

Comment: Thank you very much, it's not crashing anymore! Now i'm not getting the error messages in my route and I'm also trying to use an INSERT into the same promise.
Even rejecting the validation, it is inserting my data.
Maybe I need another promise for async reasons.

Comment: you could begin your insert function as `const addPost = post => new Promise(...)`